How do I fix this Caesar Cipher?
I am utterly green in Python and have trouble with resolving this issue.
This code snippet should encode a piece of text with letter shift. Does it make sense?
Encoding the word "no" with shift of "2" should be = "pq"
yes. The code works till here BUT backwards.
Decode the word "pq" with shift of "2" should be = "no"
BUT NO... the result is "ns" ?!
Code:
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n").lower()
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

def caesar(original_text, shift_amount, encode_or_decode):
    output_text = ""
    for letter in original_text:

        if encode_or_decode == "decode":
            shift_amount *= -1

        shifted_position = alphabet.index(letter) + shift_amount
        shifted_position %= len(alphabet)
        output_text += alphabet[shifted_position]
    print(f"Here is the {encode_or_decode}d result: {output_text}")

caesar(original_text=text, shift_amount=shift, encode_or_decode=direction)


Aside from already solved problem, you might want to have a look at the translate method togehter with the maketrans method python strings provide since they can help you to create a very compact solution to your task.

The problem is the following lines:
if encode_or_decode == "decode":
    shift_amount *= -1

The above code is "inside" the for-loop. So, for each letter it is processing, it will multiply the shift amount by -1, when it is "decoding". So, for example, suppose shift amount is 2, then the first letter has -2, but the next has -1 * -2 which is +2, the next letter as -1 * 2 which is -2, again. So, -2, +2, -2, +2, ... it is not correct.
The simplest way to fix this, is to move these 2 lines outside the for-loop. Like this:
alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

direction = input("Type 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt:\n").lower()
text = input("Type your message:\n").lower()
shift = int(input("Type the shift number:\n"))

def caesar(original_text, shift_amount, encode_or_decode):
    if encode_or_decode == "decode":
        shift_amount *= -1

    output_text = ""
    for letter in original_text:
        shifted_position = alphabet.index(letter) + shift_amount
        shifted_position %= len(alphabet)
        output_text += alphabet[shifted_position]
    print(f"Here is the {encode_or_decode}d result: {output_text}")

caesar(original_text=text, shift_amount=shift, encode_or_decode=direction)


You are flipping the shift_amount for each iteration if the encode_or_decode is set to decode, so this needs to be moved outside of the loop. Now we only change it once, and not for each letter in the text!
def caesar(original_text, shift_amount, encode_or_decode):
    output_text = ""

    if encode_or_decode == "decode":
      shift_amount *= -1

    for letter in original_text:
    'the rest of your function goes here
        


I think the you have put the if statement
 if encode_or_decode == "decode":
        shift_amount *= -1

inside the for loop, So the shift_amount is changing it's sign for each character when you are decoding
